Are "here's a Chinese snippet and my translation: is it okay?" questions on topic?
As my reading improves, I often end up in situations where I get the general idea of what a Chinese snippet means, but it's not fully accurate.  It would be nice to get some specific feedback in these situations, but I'm unsure how appropriate this would be here.
The on-topic page says this:

... Please show your attempt at translation in your question and state which area you are having difficulty with. ...

That seems easy enough.  But it also says this:

Open ended questions regarding the accuracy of a translation or asking
  for a translation of a word or passage without showing previous effort
  are not allowed.

I'm not clear on if and how this applies in my scenario.
Question: Are "here's a Chinese snippet and my translation: is it okay?" questions on topic?

Absolutely.
Show your homework and what you're having issues with and you are good to go.
The crux, as you pointed out is with:

Open ended questions regarding the accuracy of a translation

trying to avoid questions without definite answers.
I would suggest narrowing your question to one specific thing and showing what you have so far - that way, you're very unlikely to run into any off-topic problems.
